# method "onItemSelected" doesn't work in array adapter and also in fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, spinner

The method `onItemSelected` doesn't work and I don't know why.

Below is my code.

Array adapter:

```
public  class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Spinner spinner;
    ListView listView;

    /*public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }*/

    public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item);
    }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

         spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getContext(),
                R.array.country_arrays,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.println("ciao1");

      //  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        return row;
    }



   /* @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selState = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(selState);
        Toast.makeText(
                getContext(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }*/

    }
```

fragment:

```
 ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getContext());
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
//      listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i)
            {
                listView.setSelection(position);
                String selState = (String) listView.getSelectedItem();
                Toast.makeText(
                        getContext(),
                        "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

On ListViews you use onItemClicked. OnItemSelected is for Spinners. It's one of those Android nuisances...

Comment: i must use the method in array adapter or fragment?

Comment: how i must write code to take name of object into the list of spinner?

Comment: can you help me please?

Answer (score -1):

In your method of setting `OnItemSelectedListener(this)` within the `ArrayAdapter`, I believe the issue is that, because every spinner in the list references the same instance of `MyListAdapter`, your `OnItemSelected` method is not distinguishing which spinner within your list was actually selected from-- it just references the spinner object that was last set to the `MyListAdapter.spinner` reference, which should be the last one in the list.

To remedy this, don't use spinner.getSelectedItem(). Instead use  `((Spinner) parent).getSelectedItem()`, since the parent object will be the actual spinner selected from. And at that point, you should make the spinner variable local to the getView method.

In the method of calling `listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(...)` in the fragment, I expect you meant to have `listView.setOnItemClickListener(...)`, but that will listen for a click on a row in your list, not a selection from a spinner.

To detect a selection from one of your spinners, make the first modification above. To detect a click on a row in your listView as well, change to `listView.setOnItemClickListener`. Without more context for your objective or the actual errors occurring, it's hard to tell if both or just the first is desired.

EDIT:
From your comments, I think you should have this in your MyListAdapter:

```
public  class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            parent.getContext(),
            R.array.country_arrays,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    return row;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String selState = (String) ((Spinner) parent).getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(selState);
    Toast.makeText(
            parent.getContext(),
            "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

}
```

And this in your fragment (no listeners):

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getContext());
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: when i click on object, how can i show toast with name of object that i click?

Comment: After looking further at your code, I've lost some confidence. Could you clarify what you're trying to do? Your code looks like it's creating a ListView of a single row, which contains a spinner, and that seems utterly redundant. It looks as if you've hashed together examples of two different methods of creating a selectable list (a simple spinner versus a ListView with an OnItemClickListener). Do you want a list of spinners or just one spinner?

Comment: i want spinner for each row of list view and toast must tell me what object i clicked

Comment: Okay. Then if you want to display the item selected in one of the spinners, I recommend using the method of setting the listener in the adapter, but change the line
String selState = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
to 
String selState = (String) ((Spinner) parent).getSelectedItem();
And don't set a listener for the ListView in the fragment at all.

Comment: changing String selState = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem() with String selState = (String) ((Spinner) parent).getSelectedItem(); i have the same problem

Comment: Can you show what the actual error is? What is happening that's unexpected? Is it crashing, or just displaying the wrong thing? If it's crashing, the logcat would be helpful

Comment: not crash, but when i select an object into spinner, toast doesn't appear

Comment: Are you making sure to have MyListAdapter implement ArrayAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener?

Comment: if you write me complete code, i say you with precision if works or not

Comment: Sorry if you copy and pasted the code I first edited with a few minutes ago--I forgot the most important line change

Comment: Looking through the code, I can't see any reason why it wouldn't display the message. Does the line System.out.println(selState); print anything? That is, is onItemSelected called at all?

Comment: System.out.println. doesn't print Nothing because program don' t go into method onItemSelected

Comment: I'm sorry; I can't think of why it wouldn't call onItemSelected. You might instead try declaring your activity as implementing OnItemSelectedListener, moving the onItemSelected and onNothingSelected methods to the activity, and instead setting spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(parent.getContext())